# Is there a way to better translate/understand Russian to English in online reviews?

Tags: перевод

I am buying [wigs on AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32790128025.html?spm=a2g0s.8937460.0.0.23ce2e0ebZvR9l) for a performance. Many of the reviews were not in English and the site translated them. However, certain words did not translate correctly. This is especially in the Russian reviews. Thusly, I am having a hard time understanding what the reviews are actually saying. This makes it hard to select the correct wigs.

I keep seeing reviews that say that a wig/hair "climbs a little" or "does not climb", reviews that state that the wig/hair is "confused", and reviews stating that the wig/hair is "oblique".

I am trying to determine what these words actually mean. Oblique could mean that the wig is asymmetrical, but I am not entirely sure. However, this is why it would be helpful in knowing what all of these words actually mean, because I need symmetrical wigs.

This review was originally in Russian:

> Thank you to the seller, the hair looks beautiful, odorless, soft, i liked the color, comb normally, does not **climb**, i recommend!

Here is the original version in Russian:

> Спасибо продавцу,волосы красиво смотрятся,без запаха,мягкие, цвет мне понравился,расчесывать нормально,не лезет ,рекомендую!

This review was originally in Russian:

> A good wig, especially for their money, did not really like the bangs, but it's because of the styling, a little play and everything is fine, the hair is **confused**, but **walk** comb and everything is fine. So for a photo shoot i advise

Here is the original version in Russian:

> хороший парик, особенно за свои деньги,не очень понравилась челка,но это из-за укладки,чуток поиграть и все отлично,волосы путаются,но пройтись расчёской и все нормально. так что для фотосессии советую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *лезет* is the 3rd person present singular from *[лезть](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%82%D1%8C)*.

   Its main meaning is "to climb" but in this case it means "to come out, to fall off", as of the hair (see meaning 7)

   Normally it's applied to the hair itself: *у моего пса шерсть лезет*, meaning "my dog's hair come out", however, in colloquial speech, it can be applied to something that is losing the hair: *мой пёс лезет*.

   This literally means "my dog is coming out", but in the context, it's understandable that it's the hair, not the dog which is coming out.

   In your case, it's "the hair don't fall off the wig".
2. *путаются* is 3rd person present plural from *[путаться](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)*.

   It has two meanings: "to get tangled" and "to get confused".

   The Russian translation of the title of Disney's "Tangled", *Запутанная история*, is a word play on this double meaning: it means both "a tangled story" and "a confusing story".

   In your case, it's "the hair get tangled".

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it! I Googled these words but couldn't find anything solid.

Answer (score 0):

`Лезет` means it loses hair. See Wiktionary for [лезть](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%82%D1%8C), though this meaning is a colloquial contraction of [облезать](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C).

`Путаются` means hairs become entangled. Wiktionary [путаться](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F), meaning 1.

`Пройтись расчёской` means simply to comb it with a comb. See Russian Wiktionary [пройтись](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C), meaning 3: to treat a surface of an object with some tool or substance. (English one does not mention it.)

Comment: Thank you so much! You're a lifesaver! I really appreciate the link to Wikitionary, as I Googled this and couldn't find anything.